# Laravel Eloquent Query Building ORM

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-8

Let's assume, There Is two Table 'student' & 'state', 'student' table contain 'id', 'name', 'state_id'. and 'state' table contain 'id', 'state_name'. In 'student' table contain the corresponding State ID.

Now I want to fetch the student's details including the state name. (Note: In the student table, I contain only the state id) How can I achieve this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?? have the checked the laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) yet??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Student Modal

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo( State::class );
    }
}
```

Get Students With State

```
$students = Student::query()->with( 'state' )->get()
```

Search Students By State Name

```
$state = 'Dhaka';

$students = Student::query()->whereHas( 'state', function ( $query ) use ( $state ) {
    $query->where( 'state_name', 'like', "%{$state}%" );
} )->paginate( 10 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In your student model

```
public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class, 'state_id');
}
```

now you can fetch student details with the state

```
public function show($id)
{
    $student = Student::with('state')->find($id);

    //for access the state name
    //$student->state->state_name
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this helps you:

Students.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Student extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ["id", "name", "state_id"];

    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

StudentController.php

```
public function show($id)
{
    $student = Student::where('id', $id)->with('state')->get();
}
```

Comment: Why do I use User::class ?
I just want to correspond state name with student name.

Comment: That's because you should give the laravel relationship between your tables. In order to do that, you should make a relationship inside your Models.